# Is the Power BI REST API limited to one company/organization?

Tags: powerbi

Is the Power BI REST API only allowed to be called for accounts within the same organization of the application?

For example, in Azure I created a new Power BI app in the Azure Active Directory mycorp.onmicrosoft.com.

Then when using the API and redirecting the user to authenticate, it doesn't seem to work unless the user logs in as a user in the *@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com organization.

The error message is: Application with identifier '' was not found in the directory

I really hope this is not a limitation.

Comment: Is your app a web app?  What did you select for "requires user assignment"?

Comment: @Lukasz P. - Web app is a little ambiguous.  To be precise, I'd like to use the implicit OAuth2 flow for an HTML5 only (no server) client.  This is the method where no client secret should be required.  I would kill for a code example, but the only non-server example available is in C# and relies on .NET authentication libraries.  It should be possible to do everything from JavaScript.  Finally to answer your question, no I am not using "requires user assignment".

Comment: Have you looked at the ADAL JS sample? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-graphapi-web    There's a great blog post here that explains the flow in JS http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ Let me know if those aren't enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this thread.  You're right that today Power BI requires the user and the content to be in the same organization.  We do not have cross tenant sharing yet (it's something we're looking into).

Comment: Has this changed?  It looks like things might be different now.